# What's the purpose of a minipage with a single image?

Tags: floats, minipage

I am trying to clean up a LaTeX file that has a lot of images. Many of them are included within a minipage in a figure:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{image.jpg}
        \caption{This is the caption}
        \label{somelabel}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

I do not understand why this is done and would simply remove the minipage -- the result seems to be the same. But I am curious whether I may have missed a deeper reason?

Comment: In my opinion, it is useless!

Comment: if cleaning up the source  you should most likely change `[!ht]` as well. `!` should only be used in exceptional cases, and mostly if you use the optional argument, it should include `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title asks abiut a minipage with a single image. A minipage with a single image and a `\caption` is useful, and can be positioned by various means.

But your example is of a figure enviornment that just consists of a single minipage that contains no footnotes, the minipage is doing nothing useful in such a case. Arguably if your document has a lot of notes in captions and is using minipage to allow `\footnote` to be used, then it might make sense to always use a minipage in case you want to add a footnote, but as shown, the minipage is doing nothing.